# RequestParam shows null value

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to retrieve the value from view and use it in controller by using RequestParam. However, the RequestParam attribute shows null.
Below is my code -
JSP Page

```
    <form th:action="@{/schedule}" method="post">
        <!-- page start-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h3 class="page-header"><i class="fa fa fa-bars"></i> SCHEDULE APPOINTMENT </h3>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
              <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i><a th:href="@{/index}">Home</a></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>Pages</li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>Page</li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
             
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="appointmentDatePicker" class="col-form-label">Select Date<font color="red">*</font></label>
                    <input type="date" id="appointmentDatePicker" name="appointmentDatePicker" onchange="myFunction()" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">        
                    <label for="appointmentDate" class="col-form-label">Date</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="appointmentDate" name="appointmentDate" readonly="readonly">
                    <script>
                    function myFunction() {
                      //document.getElementById("2").disabled = true;
                        //var j = document.getElementById("appointmentDate");
                        //j.innerHTML = document.getElementById("appointmentDatePicker").value;
                        var aptDate = document.getElementById("appointmentDatePicker").value;
                        alert(aptDate);
                        document.getElementById("appointmentDate").value = aptDate;
                    }
                    </script>
            </div>
            <a th:href="@{/viewApp}">View Appointments</a>  
        </div>
       
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="appointment" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">List of Available appointment slots</label>
                <select id="appointmentId" name="appointmentId" >
                   <option value="">Please Select</option>                                                                              
                   <option th:each="appointment : ${appointmentList}"
                        th:unless="${appointment.appointmentStatus}"
                        th:value="${appointment.appointmentId}"
                        th:text="${appointment.displayTime}">
                   </option>
                </select>
          </div>  
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Schedule Appointment</button>    
          </form>
 <!-- page end-->
```

Controller code

```
@GetMapping("/viewApp") 
    public String ViewAppointmentList(Model model ,  RedirectAttributes redir, 
                                                    @RequestParam(value ="appointmentDate", required = false) String appointmentDate
                                                    ,@RequestParam(value ="appointmentDatePicker", required = false) String appointmentDatePicker) {
        System.out.println("In view of scheduleApp");
        
          System.out.println("Date is "+appointmentDate); 
          System.out.println("appointmentDatePicker " +appointmentDatePicker);
        
            //get the date set
          List<Appointment> appointmentList = appointmentService.getAppointments();
          appointmentList.forEach(appointment -> appointment.setDisplayTime(appointment.getTimeFrom(),appointment.getTimeTo()));
          
          List<Appointment> appointmentListByDate = new ArrayList<Appointment>(); 
          for (Appointment appointment:appointmentList) 
          { 
              //if condition to filter depending upon date
                  appointment.setDisplayTime(appointment.getTimeFrom(),appointment.getTimeTo()); appointmentListByDate.add(appointment);
                  System.out.println("appointment date " + appointment.getTimeFrom()); 
                  
          }
          
          //model.addAttribute("appointmentList", appointmentListByDate);       
          redir.addFlashAttribute("appointmentList", appointmentListByDate);
        
          return "redirect:/scheduleApp";
    }
```

The console shows as below

```
In view of scheduleApp
Date is null
appointmentDatePicker null
```

Edited JSP page code to show the form code.
I'm newbie to MVC and can someone correct me where I'm wrong?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Looking at the snippets I would say there is no form, so nothing to submit. Also on the initial rendering there will nothing selected so the fields are `null` anyway.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for your reply. I have added the form code too above. I'm selecting the appointment date and then click on view appointments hyperlink, so i believe the form should not show the date null.

Comment: No it shouldn't. Clicking a link isn't submitting a form.